# What is the verb form of "LLC"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, analogy

I want to say something similar to this:

> Founded in April of 2005, and incorporated in 2006, Example Company is now the leading news site.

But my company is not incorporated, we are an LLC. How can I say something with the similar feel as the above statement?

Comment: You weren't an LLC right from the start?

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 - websites often just start, only becoming LLC if they get out of the hobby phase.

Comment: Lots of businesses start out as sole proprietorships or partnerships, and later become corporations or LLCs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not look for the verb form of Limited Liability Company, I would just use *become*:

> Founded in April 2005, and then becoming an LLC in 2006, Example Company is now the leading news site.

Answer (score 3):

At least in the legal idiom, "formed," "organized," and in many jurisdictions, "chartered" are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As presumably Example Company remains an LLC, you could write

> Founded in April of 2005 and an LLC since 2006, Example Company is...

By saying "an LLC since 2006", it implies that that was when it first became an LLC (it was not an LLC before that date), which is just what you want to say. This is slightly more concise than your other options.

Answer (score 1):

How about *structured* or *re-structured*?

> Founded in April of 2005, and LLC-structured in 2006, Example Company is
>   now the leading news site.

Comment: Re-structured is good, but I would sooner write "re-structured as an LLC" than "LLC-structured" except in extremely informal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

`Incorporation` is still correct. An LLC is a *limited liability **corporation***, but it is still class of *corporation*, and thus, it must have been *incorporated*.

Comment: Wikipedia (s.v. "LLC"): Often incorrectly called a "limited liability corporation" (instead of company), it is a hybrid business entity having certain characteristics of both a corporation and a partnership or sole proprietorship (depending on how many owners there are). An LLC, although a business entity, is a type of unincorporated association and is not a corporation.

Comment: ok -- I stand corrected, however, i still believe incorporated is fair use in this instance.

Comment: This is not correct. There are two types of corporations, a C-corp and an S-corp. As @zpletan said, an LLC, or limited liability company, is a company. An LLC has not been incorporated. That is the purpose of incorporation, to shift liability from the individuals to the company. This happens to be consistent with Wikipedia, and also with any accounting, legal, government or business usage in the U.S.A.